# Laravel Write Update Test

Tags: laravel, testing

I'm using Laravel 8 starting with cloned pingcrm and I'm tryng to write a test to update a contact, but seems it doesn't work.
Note that I made a change to the preset structure, now a contact is directly associated to the user that created it (not to the account)

```js
    public function test_an_authorized_user_can_update_a_contact()
    {
        $this->user->contacts()->saveMany(
            factory(Contact::class, 5)->make()
        );

        $this->actingAs($this->user)
            ->put('/contacts/' . Contact::first()->id, ['first_name' => 'bablo']);
        // TRIED PATCH TOO
        // TRIED '/contacts' AS WELL


        dd(Contact::first());
    }
```

The extracted contact was not updated. Suggestions?

EDIT

I get the following error from the request

```html
 +response: null
  +status: 422
  +errorBag: "default"
  +redirectTo: null
  #message: "The given data was invalid."
  #code: 0
  #file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\myhobbies\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php"
  #line: 452
  trace: {
    C:\xampp\htdocs\myhobbies\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php:452 { …}
    C:\xampp\htdocs\myhobbies\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Factory.php:136 { …}
    C:\xampp\htdocs\myhobbies\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider.php:58 { …}
    Illuminate\Http\Request->Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\{closure}() {}
    C:\xampp\htdocs\myhobbies\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Macroable\Traits\Macroable.php:111 { …}
    C:\xampp\htdocs\myhobbies\app\Http\Controllers\ContactsController.php:128 {
      App\Http\Controllers\ContactsController->validateData()
      › return request()->validate([\r
      ›     'first_name' => ['required', 'max:50'],\r
      ›     'last_name' => ['required', 'max:50'],\r
      arguments: {
        $method: "validate"
        $parameters: array:1 [ …1]
      }
    }
    C:\xampp\htdocs\myhobbies\app\Http\Controllers\ContactsController.php:103 { …}
    App\Http\Controllers\ContactsController->update() {}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/inertiajs/pingcrm/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/ContactsController.php#L98 Based on this, you're missing some required fields.

Comment: @NicoHaase used dd()

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier Now I've tried this as well
array_merge(Contact::first()->toArray(), ['first_name' => 'bablo'])
But still doesn't work

Comment: But the update in the API works

Comment: Why not start up XDebug and see where this goes wrong?

Comment: The `organization_id` must also be owned by the current user *(or null)*

Comment: organization_id is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [source](https://github.com/inertiajs/pingcrm/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/ContactsController.php#L98) you're missing some required fields

```
public function update(Contact $contact)
    {
        $contact->update(
            Request::validate([
                'first_name' => ['required', 'max:50'],
                'last_name' => ['required', 'max:50'],
                'organization_id' => ['nullable', Rule::exists('organizations', 'id')->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('account_id', Auth::user()->account_id);
                })],
                'email' => ['nullable', 'max:50', 'email'],
                'phone' => ['nullable', 'max:50'],
                'address' => ['nullable', 'max:150'],
                'city' => ['nullable', 'max:50'],
                'region' => ['nullable', 'max:50'],
                'country' => ['nullable', 'max:2'],
                'postal_code' => ['nullable', 'max:25'],
            ])
        );

        return Redirect::back()->with('success', 'Contact updated.');
    }
```

You can add this to your test to assert you don't have any error

```
public function test_an_authorized_user_can_update_a_contact()
{
    // One possibility to see the detail of the error
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling(); 

    $this->user->contacts()->saveMany(
        factory(Contact::class, 5)->make()
    );

    $this->actingAs($this->user)
         ->put('/contacts/' . Contact::first()->id, ['first_name' => 'bablo'])
         // ->assertStatus(200)
         ;

     // second possibility to see the errors
     $errors = session('errors');
     dd($errors->all());
}
```

Comment: Try adding `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` in the first line of your test.

Comment: I believe you can also get the errors by doing something like `dd(session('errors')->all())`

Comment: Ok problem was that first name and last name are required, still don't understand why the array_merge doesn't work, maybe because I'm tryng to force the id?

Comment: It could be that the fake data doesn't respect the validation rules neither.